# MYSQL: How to aggregate events data

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a table stored events data in the following form

```
User   Event_type
1      A
3      B
1      B
2      C
```

I want to count for each user number of certain type of events (Not all user have all events)

expected result

```
User   #Event_A  #Event_B   #Event_C
1      1         1          0
2      0         0          1
3      0         1          0
```

How can I achieve this most concisely ?

Comment: This transformation is called pivoting and has been asked and answered here on SO several times. The linked duplicate topic escribes both static and dynamic pivoting. Pls note that it may be more effective to perform such transformations within the application logic, rather than in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    `User`,
    SUM(IF(Event_type = "A", 1, 0)) AS "#EventA",
    SUM(IF(Event_type = "B", 1, 0)) AS "#EventB",
    SUM(IF(Event_type = "C", 1, 0)) AS "#EventC"
FROM
    yourtable
GROUP BY
    `User`
```

If you were going to have a ton of events, you could build the SUM IF statements dynamically in a loop using the results of `SELECT DISTINCT(Event_type) FROM yourtable`

Comment: No need to loop, see the duplicate topic.

Comment: I see thanks.  It may be easier though to loop in a scripting language and just build strings like 'SUM(IF(Event_type = "'+event+'", 1, 0)) AS "#Event'+event+'"', and just get the job done though in some cases.

Comment: The whole pivoting transformation is usually more effectively done in a proper programming language, than in SQL :)